# Spotfire to transform text value before loading

Tags: transformation, spotfire

Folks,

I've column [A] with various texts and need to transform that text (i.e., replace with abbreviations) before loading.

So, a table has values: J1, J2, J3, PLAB, CIVIL, ENGG etc.

I need to transform it to "J1" to "Java", "J2" to "Stack", while keeping the PLAB, CIVIL & ENGG as they are.

Hope I am clear.

PS: I don't need a calculated column, as column [A] has other text that does not need transformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done when you add the data table to the analytic.

- File > Add Data Table > (Select your data)
- At the bottom of the window, you will see *Transformations*... select **Calculate and replace column**
- Add the expression below, and give it the same column name as the original column
- Select **OK**

**Custom Expression:**

```
case
   when [yourColumn] = 'J1' then 'Java'
   when [yourColumn] = 'J2' then 'Stack'
   else [yourColumn]
end
```

Comment: Kudos to you, scsimon!

Comment: No worries at all @desibird